# Why is CoreMinimal.h not found in the Unreal code editor?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am following along with a tutorial in Unreal, and I am at a part where we generated a C++ class as a component for a static mesh prop. Right after the code was generated, I see an error at the top of my text file that I don't see on the instructor's screen in the tutorial.

The error says `'CoreMinimal.h' file not found`

Is this supposed to be this way? Is there something wrong with my setup?

I am running UnrealEditor 4.16.1.

Comment: *" I see an error at the top of my text file"* You mean the compiler points to that line when it fails to compile? Or are you talking about some sort of Editor feature (Intellisense etc.)?

Comment: It's the editor feature. I am using xcode 8.3.2

Comment: Then you can safely ignore it. Editors aren't always able to find the header files, especially in more complex setups (such as game engines), or sometimes they take a long time to parse the entire configuration. You only need to worry if the compiler can't find it

Comment: @UnholySheep but in my case, the file is not compiling. the compiler detected that line as an error.